# Pegando o nome da Impressora Padrão

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Consigo pegar o nome da impressora padrão declarado Printers na seção uses:

```
Printer.Printers[Printer.PrinterIndex]
```

Se por acaso, durante a execução do programa o usuário trocar a impressora padrão. Como eu consigo pegar essa nova impressora(nome da impressora)?

Comment: Eu tentaria usar um evento

Comment: Seria só executar todas as vezes `Printer.Printers[Printer.PrinterIndex]` que precisar, a não ser que uma aplicação Delphi salve em algum tipo de cache na memoria as impressoras. Mas não entendo muito da tecnologia.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não funciona, se eu chamar o método Printer.Printers[Printer.PrinterIndex] vai trazer a impressora padrão, agora se eu mudar a impressora padrão sem fechar minha aplicação e chamar novamente o método Printer.Printers[Printer.PrinterIndex] vai continuar trazendo a primeira impressora padrão, agora se reiniciar o programa, e chamar o método dai atualiza a impressora padrão.

Comment: Mas você executa inteiro `Printer.Printers[Printer.PrinterIndex]` ou apenas pega a variavel que recebeu o valor do item deste index especifico?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento executo inteiro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe uma tratativa no Set da propriedade PrinterIndex, quando passar o valor -1 ele sempre retornará a impressora padrão do windows. Ex:

```
if Printer.Printers.Count > 0 then
begin
  Printer.PrinterIndex := -1;
  ShowMessage(Printer.Printers[Printer.PrinterIndex]);
end;
```